# Scala Object Instantiotion on Run Time

Tags: json, scala, parsing, playframework

I am working on an API with Scala and Play Framework. When the API receive a request with a JSON the first value within the json gives the name of the class which the object is going to be created (and that is the second value in the received JSON). Basically I get a string value lets say that MyClassName and later I have to create an object of MyClassName which is already defined in the program.

What is the easiest / cleanest way of doing this ? The only solution I came up with is to make a match / case but since I have tens of classes this is not the best way.

Comment: Did you consider using play-json https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson?

Comment: @JhonnyEverson For parsing yes I am using Json.format with companion objects to parse objects automatically.

Comment: For example :  {"objectType": "MyObject", "myObjectConfiguratipn": "{//All the field values for my object as escaped json object in a string}"} my aim is to convert this into a myObject: MyObject  @JhonnyEverson

Answer (score 0):

If the classes are already defined and the property defined in the value matches the names of the class, you can use `Class.forName`

Comment: That function adds $ signs to class names. I am looking for an alernative to that. @JhonnyEverson